# Get linked data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase structure looks like this:
[image: user structure]
The groups use keys generated by firebase, 0 and 1 are just examples.
[image]
  In those groups there is more data like "groupname".

**How should I retrieve the groupnames of all groups linked to a user?**
  I'm on Android.

Solved by Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `groups` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and inside a single group, there is a key named `groupName`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference groupsRef = rootRef.child("groups");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);  
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
};
groupsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

If you need to be able to get only the group names of the groups that your users are linking to, you need to query twice like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userGroupsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userKey).child("groups");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String groupKey = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference groupKeyRef = rootRef.child("groups").child(groupKey);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
                }
            };
            groupKeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
};
userGroupsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `userKey` is the key of the user from which you want the get the group ids.

Comment: Doesn't this return *all* the group names instead of the group names of a specific users groups?

Comment: That will indeed get me all the groupnames of all my groups. But I want to be able to only get the groupnames of the groups that my user is linking to.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf No it doesn't. It returns the groupnames of all my groups.

Comment: To be able to get only the groupnames of the groups that my user is linking to, you need to query twice. Once to get those keys and then using those keys, to get the actual names.

Comment: Do you how to do it?

Comment: @AlexMamo How I have to do that double query is my question. Could you show how to do that?

Comment: Please see my updaed answer.

Comment: I get the correct data in "groupkey". But groupName has the value null and there are too many groupnames for the amount of groups I have linked to the user. 42 times it prints the groupname but only 8 groupnames should be there.

Comment: Please share also what inside the childrens of the groups node (only one). Add a new prin-screen.

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Should print now only the 8 group names.

Comment: Mistake at my end. It is now only showing the group names that are linked to the user that is logedin. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use `Log.d("TAG", groupKey);` right after this line of code `String groupKey = ds.getKey();` , what is the result?

Comment: @AlexMamo is there a reason that you are not using the `interface` with this solution?

Comment: @Learn2Code There is no need for that. Nesting Realtime Database calls work just fine. Nowadays, however, there are other [ways](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) in which we can perform asynchronous calls.